# Meteor Up Setup Error on DigitalOcean

Tags: meteor

I am trying to deploy a Meteor app onto a DigitalOcean droplet, via its IP address (I have no domain name). I am doing this kind of thing for the first time, and am having a lot of issues with it.

This is my droplet on Digital Ocean:

[image: Digital Ocean droplet]

I created a [MUP (Meteor Up)](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up) directory outside my Meteor app’s repo using `mup init`, and this is the `mup.js` file that I have:

```
module.exports = {
    servers: {
        one: {
            host: 'http://162.243.57.207',
            username: 'cs673f16',
            pem: '/Users/gautambhat/.ssh/id_rsa'
            // password:
            // or leave blank for authenticate from ssh-agent
        }
    },

    meteor: {
        name: 'meetcute',
        path: '/Users/gautambhat/Repos/CS673_team2',
        servers: {
            one: {}
        },
        buildOptions: {
        serverOnly: true,
        },
        env: {
            ROOT_URL: 'http://162.243.57.207',
            PORT : 3000
            //MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor'
        },

        //dockerImage: 'kadirahq/meteord'
        deployCheckWaitTime: 60
    },

    mongo: {
        oplog: true,
        port: 27017,
        servers: {
            one: {},
        },
    },
};
```

Also, I don't know my MONGO_URL, or where to find it, so I just commented it out. On running `mup setup`, I get the following error:

```
Started TaskList: Setup Docker
[http://162.243.57.207] - setup docker
Error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://162.243.57.207 http://162.243.57.207:22
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error—[as described in your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41080177/2)—is as follows:

```
Started TaskList: Setup Docker
[http://162.243.57.207] - setup docker
Error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://162.243.57.207 http://162.243.57.207:22
```

The error basically means it can’t find the host `http://162.243.57.207`. So let’s look at the `servers part of your configuration:

```
servers: {
    one: {
        host: 'http://162.243.57.207',
        username: 'cs673f16',
        pem: '/Users/gautambhat/.ssh/id_rsa'
        // password:
        // or leave blank for authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
},
```

Your `host` setting is a URL when it should be a hostname or IP address; meaning `host: 'http://162.243.57.207'` should just be `162.243.57.207`. So change that and try again:

```
servers: {
    one: {
        host: '162.243.57.207',
        username: 'cs673f16',
        pem: '/Users/gautambhat/.ssh/id_rsa'
        // password:
        // or leave blank for authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
},
```

Comment: I'm getting errors with deployment, edited my post to show those errors

Comment: I see. I can close this question, or revert it back to its previous form